# How to Ignore error in batch insert Postgresql

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, knex.js

I have a process that runs every 5 minutes and tries to insert a batch of articles into a table. The articles come from web-scraping, so there are cases in which I am trying to insert a batch that contains articles which have already been saved into the DB.

My primary key is `uuid` - an MD5 hash of the article title.

Checking if an article exists in the db to filter the batch is kinda inefficient.

Is it a DB level way in Postgresql to ignore the attempts of inserting a duplicate `uuid` without returning an Error?

Comment: `ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING` is the simplest way to acheive this

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Solution

You could insert using the `WHERE NOT EXISTS` clause.

For example, consider a `test` table with a numeric `id` as primary key and a textual `name`.

## Code

```sql
db=> CREATE TABLE test(id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT);
CREATE TABLE

-- Insertion will work - empty table
db=> INSERT INTO test(id, name) 
     SELECT 1, 'Partner number 1' 
     WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1,2 FROM test WHERE id=1);
INSERT 0 1

-- Insertion will NOT work - duplicate id
db=> INSERT INTO test(id, name) 
     SELECT 1, 'Partner number 1' 
     WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1,2 FROM test WHERE id=1);    
INSERT 0 0

-- After two insertions, the table contains only one row
db=> SELECT * FROM test;
 id |       name
----+------------------
  1 | Partner number 1
(1 row)
```

## Difference from `ON CONFLICT`

Quoting [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-insert.html):

> `ON CONFLICT` can be used to specify an alternative action to raising a unique constraint or exclusion constraint violation error.

[The action can be](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT) `DO NOTHING`, or a `DO UPDATE`. The second approach is often referred to as *Upsert* - a portmanteau of Insert and Update.

Technically `WHERE NOT EXISTS` is equivalent to `ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING`. See the query plans for a deeper dive.

Comment: is it the same as doing `ON CONFLICT  DO NOTHING;` ?

Comment: @AvraamMavridis Updated my answer

Comment: watch out for the TYPO in word CONFLICT (here conFILct)

Answer (score 0):

You could try SQL MERGE:

https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/SQL_MERGE

Merge can insert, if predicates are not matched(in your case, `uuid`).

Similar option is UPSERT:

https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/UPSERT

Comment: Note that these options are only available with the latest PostgreSQL versions.

Comment: UPSERT is not itself a command, it is a "way to use" INSERT .. ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE